# FAST algorithm in opencv

Tags: opencv, slam

the question can be tough I think as I use orbslam2 and modify it. orbslam2 use FAST in opencv to detect feature. In orbslam2 ORBextractor.cc it has the following line

```
FAST(mvImagePyramid[level].rowRange(iniY,maxY).colRange(iniX,maxX),vKeysCell,iniThFAST,true);
```

It runs totally all right. However, after I use the code [here](https://github.com/jingpang/LearnVIORB/blob/RT/src/ORBextractor.cc)(it changes orbslam to visual inertial slam, but don't worry about this...)
When I run the visual inertial orbslam, it doesn't modify the orbslam part. But it will stop at FAST and returns segmentation fault(core sumped).
But the weird thing is the code in original orbslam code and the code above have the totally same input. I print out the input of FAST. It is

```
[ 18,  19,  20,  21,  21,  24,  26,  27,  26,  26,  28,  27,  27,  28,  28,  27,  26,  26,  27,  24,  26,  25,  28,  28,  28,  29,  31,  31,  32,  33,  32,  30,  28,  28,  26,  23;
  19,  23,  23,  24,  24,  27,  26,  29,  29,  30,  32,  34,  29,  31,  31,  28,  31,  30,  32,  30,  29,  28,  30,  31,  31,  34,  35,  34,  35,  35,  33,  34,  32,  30,  26,  24;
  27,  27,  30,  29,  26,  28,  27,  30,  30,  33,  31,  30,  28,  31,  31,  32,  31,  31,  33,  32,  32,  29,  31,  32,  31,  33,  34,  34,  36,  35,  35,  33,  33,  31,  27,  23;
  29,  31,  32,  32,  34,  30,  31,  32,  33,  31,  29,  29,  30,  31,  30,  31,  31,  30,  31,  32,  31,  32,  34,  32,  31,  33,  34,  33,  35,  33,  34,  35,  34,  32,  27,  24;
  32,  31,  33,  35,  35,  34,  32,  31,  30,  29,  28,  27,  29,  30,  30,  32,  30,  31,  30,  31,  31,  32,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  36,  34,  33,  33,  33,  31,  29,  23;
  32,  31,  34,  35,  35,  33,  33,  31,  29,  28,  29,  30,  30,  29,  29,  28,  31,  30,  31,  30,  30,  32,  35,  35,  35,  34,  34,  34,  35,  34,  33,  33,  33,  31,  27,  23;
  31,  33,  33,  33,  34,  32,  31,  33,  31,  32,  29,  30,  31,  28,  30,  31,  31,  30,  30,  32,  32,  31,  33,  32,  33,  35,  33,  34,  35,  33,  32,  35,  31,  31,  28,  25;
  34,  33,  32,  32,  33,  32,  34,  31,  33,  31,  31,  33,  31,  31,  33,  32,  33,  31,  33,  32,  34,  33,  34,  35,  38,  36,  34,  33,  33,  35,  35,  32,  31,  28,  27,  23;
  30,  32,  30,  31,  32,  32,  31,  32,  31,  31,  32,  32,  34,  33,  34,  36,  36,  38,  35,  37,  37,  36,  37,  40,  36,  37,  35,  32,  32,  33,  31,  30,  28,  29,  27,  22;
  33,  32,  29,  31,  32,  32,  30,  31,  33,  31,  33,  34,  34,  38,  38,  37,  39,  37,  37,  35,  37,  36,  37,  36,  37,  36,  35,  31,  33,  34,  30,  32,  30,  29,  28,  24;
  33,  33,  32,  31,  31,  29,  33,  33,  34,  33,  35,  34,  35,  36,  38,  37,  39,  36,  37,  37,  36,  36,  38,  36,  36,  34,  36,  35,  32,  34,  34,  32,  34,  32,  28,  24;
  33,  32,  31,  32,  30,  32,  34,  32,  30,  33,  36,  35,  35,  35,  39,  39,  40,  36,  38,  39,  40,  39,  40,  39,  38,  39,  37,  33,  35,  34,  33,  34,  33,  35,  29,  25;
  33,  34,  34,  34,  34,  34,  33,  36,  37,  37,  37,  37,  39,  40,  39,  40,  40,  39,  38,  37,  41,  40,  40,  41,  40,  41,  38,  37,  37,  36,  35,  34,  35,  31,  28,  24;
  32,  34,  34,  33,  35,  36,  34,  39,  39,  38,  38,  40,  41,  40,  41,  38,  38,  41,  41,  39,  41,  41,  40,  39,  42,  40,  41,  39,  38,  37,  38,  37,  35,  30,  30,  25;
  35,  34,  34,  34,  36,  38,  38,  40,  39,  39,  43,  41,  41,  40,  38,  40,  40,  41,  39,  40,  40,  40,  39,  40,  40,  41,  40,  40,  38,  38,  37,  36,  34,  32,  28,  24;
  38,  35,  36,  34,  35,  33,  34,  37,  38,  38,  38,  39,  39,  41,  40,  40,  40,  40,  39,  41,  40,  43,  41,  41,  42,  42,  42,  39,  39,  39,  40,  36,  36,  30,  28,  23;
  39,  40,  37,  38,  40,  37,  37,  37,  36,  37,  39,  38,  40,  39,  39,  40,  40,  41,  40,  42,  41,  40,  40,  41,  40,  39,  42,  39,  40,  41,  36,  36,  34,  32,  29,  25;
  37,  38,  38,  41,  38,  39,  37,  38,  38,  39,  41,  40,  40,  39,  39,  39,  42,  41,  39,  41,  40,  43,  41,  41,  40,  41,  42,  39,  42,  38,  37,  35,  34,  30,  26,  23;
  38,  39,  39,  39,  38,  37,  39,  40,  40,  41,  40,  41,  40,  42,  38,  39,  40,  39,  40,  43,  42,  39,  40,  41,  38,  40,  39,  40,  40,  38,  35,  35,  35,  31,  28,  25;
  39,  39,  39,  38,  41,  41,  39,  39,  40,  39,  41,  41,  41,  41,  40,  40,  39,  40,  40,  40,  40,  41,  41,  40,  39,  39,  40,  38,  40,  36,  36,  36,  34,  33,  28,  24;
  38,  39,  39,  39,  39,  39,  40,  38,  39,  39,  42,  41,  41,  40,  40,  38,  40,  39,  38,  41,  42,  42,  39,  39,  40,  37,  40,  39,  37,  38,  36,  35,  34,  32,  31,  25;
  40,  38,  37,  39,  38,  41,  40,  40,  38,  40,  42,  43,  44,  40,  40,  40,  37,  41,  40,  41,  41,  41,  40,  39,  42,  43,  40,  39,  37,  38,  36,  37,  35,  33,  30,  25;
  38,  38,  39,  38,  40,  39,  40,  39,  41,  42,  40,  39,  42,  40,  40,  38,  38,  43,  41,  39,  40,  40,  40,  40,  41,  39,  41,  42,  37,  37,  37,  36,  35,  32,  31,  24;
  40,  38,  39,  40,  39,  40,  40,  40,  41,  40,  40,  41,  42,  39,  38,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  40,  40,  42,  42,  39,  42,  41,  43,  40,  37,  37,  39,  36,  35,  31,  27;
  38,  39,  40,  40,  40,  39,  41,  42,  39,  39,  41,  42,  41,  42,  42,  39,  42,  41,  42,  42,  43,  42,  41,  42,  41,  43,  42,  41,  38,  38,  37,  36,  36,  33,  31,  25;
  40,  40,  41,  40,  40,  39,  41,  41,  41,  41,  43,  43,  41,  42,  41,  42,  41,  44,  44,  44,  43,  43,  43,  44,  43,  42,  42,  43,  40,  39,  40,  35,  38,  37,  32,  28;
  42,  41,  41,  42,  40,  41,  41,  43,  44,  42,  42,  44,  42,  41,  43,  44,  44,  41,  43,  45,  44,  46,  43,  44,  44,  43,  43,  41,  42,  39,  39,  38,  39,  34,  33,  28;
  42,  40,  43,  41,  42,  41,  42,  44,  44,  42,  44,  44,  43,  42,  44,  43,  43,  42,  44,  44,  46,  44,  43,  45,  44,  43,  44,  44,  43,  41,  38,  39,  37,  35,  31,  28;
  43,  41,  40,  43,  43,  42,  44,  44,  43,  43,  43,  44,  44,  43,  43,  43,  44,  44,  44,  43,  43,  43,  43,  44,  45,  42,  43,  45,  48,  41,  40,  39,  37,  33,  31,  29;
  42,  42,  43,  43,  42,  42,  42,  44,  44,  42,  46,  42,  44,  45,  44,  45,  44,  43,  42,  43,  44,  43,  44,  41,  42,  42,  43,  45,  40,  43,  38,  38,  37,  35,  33,  28;
  41,  41,  43,  41,  42,  42,  42,  41,  42,  43,  43,  44,  45,  44,  45,  43,  45,  45,  44,  44,  44,  43,  44,  43,  41,  40,  43,  42,  40,  44,  39,  39,  37,  35,  33,  28;
  39,  41,  41,  41,  43,  41,  43,  44,  44,  42,  44,  45,  46,  44,  46,  45,  45,  45,  44,  46,  45,  45,  45,  45,  43,  43,  40,  41,  40,  41,  40,  39,  36,  35,  33,  28;
  42,  41,  42,  44,  43,  42,  45,  45,  42,  43,  44,  44,  46,  44,  42,  43,  42,  44,  43,  43,  43,  42,  44,  46,  42,  42,  39,  42,  40,  41,  39,  37,  36,  35,  33,  28;
  41,  43,  42,  44,  44,  43,  44,  42,  41,  44,  42,  44,  46,  42,  42,  41,  40,  41,  43,  41,  42,  44,  45,  43,  42,  43,  43,  41,  41,  40,  40,  38,  39,  37,  32,  29;
  41,  41,  41,  43,  42,  41,  43,  42,  42,  43,  45,  44,  45,  43,  40,  38,  32,  32,  41,  41,  42,  41,  42,  44,  43,  44,  44,  43,  42,  41,  41,  38,  37,  35,  32,  30;
  40,  42,  42,  43,  41,  41,  42,  40,  42,  41,  44,  44,  44,  44,  42,  35,  31,  30,  36,  43,  44,  45,  43,  42,  42,  42,  44,  44,  42,  41,  38,  36,  36,  33,  32,  29;
  36,  41,  40,  41,  42,  41,  43,  42,  40,  43,  42,  44,  42,  42,  44,  38,  33,  36,  40,  42,  42,  41,  42,  40,  40,  42,  42,  42,  40,  37,  38,  37,  37,  34,  34,  31;
  39,  40,  40,  41,  42,  41,  43,  43,  41,  42,  42,  42,  42,  43,  43,  40,  38,  40,  38,  41,  40,  40,  42,  43,  42,  44,  44,  43,  41,  40,  39,  37,  38,  35,  34,  30]
nCols: 24 nRows: 14 maxY : 54 maxX: 52 iniY: 16 iniX: 16 iniThFAST is 20
```

I double make sure that every number is the same, so FAST has totally the same input. So what could be the problem? Thanks for answer!!